# How to increase the ipython qtconsole scrollback buffer limit

Tags: buffer, limit, ipython, output, qtconsole

When I load ipython with any one of:

```
ipython qtconsole
ipython qtconsole --pylab
ipython qtconsole --pylab inline
```

The output buffer only holds the last 500 lines. To see this run:

```
for x in range(0, 501):
   ...:     print x
```

Is there a configuration option for this? 
I've tried adjusting --cache-size but this does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quickly:

ipython qtconsole --IPythonWidget.buffer_size=1000

Or you can set it permanently by adding:

```
c.IPythonWidget.buffer_size=1000
```

in your ipython config file.

For discovering this sort of thing, a helpful trick is:

```
ipython qtconsole --help-all | grep PATTERN
```

For instance, you already had 'buffer', so:

```
$> ipython qtconsole --help-all | grep -C 3 buffer
...
--IPythonWidget.buffer_size=<Integer>
    Default: 500
    The maximum number of lines of text before truncation. Specifying a non-
    positive number disables text truncation (not recommended).
```

If IPython used a different name than you expect and that first search turned up nothing, then you could use `500`, since you knew what the value was that you wanted to change, which would also find the relevant config.

Comment: Excellent. Every suggestion works.  Thanks also for the algorithm to find other configuration options.

Note that the configuration file -- which I thought contained all the defaults -- does not mention buffer_size.

Comment: ipython_qtconsole_config.py would be the relevant one. It should be in there.  If not, you might generate a fresh config `ipython profile create fresh`, and look in there.

Comment: I didn't have ipython_qtconsole_config.py . 
But now 'ipython profile create fresh' makes one. 

Hmm. Speculation: This may be because qtconsole was not originally functional in fedora 17. I had to manually 'pip-python install pygments' to get 'ipython qtconsole' to work.  By that time I may have already created the profiles.

Comment: yes, the qtconsole must be importable in order to generate the default config file.

Comment: I have set that number to `10,000` but it seems internally it cannot go back further than 1000 with history-search-backward. I open the `sqlite` file and it has commands from more than a year ago (53000 lines) but the history does no go back.

Comment: This does not work with Jupyter QtConsole anymore and I cannot find the appropriate new settings

Comment: For Jupyter QtConsole the config file is `jupyter_qtconsole_config.py` and the line you need to add is `c.JupyterWidget.buffer_size=1000`. Note that (on Windows at least) the config file is stored in the `~/.jupyter` directory. I couldn't find a way to generate this config file so I just made an empty one.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is no longer correct if you are using [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/). Instead, the command line option should be:

```sh
jupyter qtconsole --ConsoleWidget.buffer_size=5000
```

You can choose whatever value you want, just make it larger than the default of 500.

If you want to make this permanent, go to your home directory - `C:\Users\username`, `/Users/username`, or `/home/username` - then go into the `.jupyter` folder (create it if it doesn't exist), then create the file `jupyter_qtconsole_config.py` and open it up in your favorite editor. Add the following line:

```py
c.ConsoleWidget.buffer_size=5000
```

Again, the number can be anything, just as long as it is an integer larger than 500. Don't worry that `c` isn't defined in this particular file, it is already defined elsewhere in the startup machinery.

---

Thanks to [@firescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720766/how-to-increase-the-ipython-qtconsole-scrollback-buffer-limit#comment64077925_14722936) for the pointer in the right direction.