# Setting the working directory of IPython Shell to that of the python file being executed in Canopy

Tags: editor, ipython, enthought

I am new to IPython and I am using the Canopy distribution. The default value of the shell's working directory is /home/username. This is a bit painful, when I work on files which need other files present in the corresponding folder that I am working in.

So, I always manually change it to folder in which the file (which I am trying to execute) is present.

I found this [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680463/change-ipython-working-directory), but my question is slightly different. Also, I couldn't understand the answer provided there really well.

Is there a shorter way of setting up the working directory of the IPython shell to that of the file on which I am working? Like a command?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature that is on our list of features, but quite low on priority.  Canopy provides a right click context menu option to switch to the currently active editor's directory (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16848410/1225068)).

Also, as a temporary work-around, you could use the following macro to get your job done.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def run():
    code_task = get_active_task()

    from os.path import dirname

    def change_directory():
        code_editor = code_task.active_editor
        if not code_editor:
            return
        python_pane = code_task.python_pane
        active_dir = dirname(code_editor.obj.path)
        python_pane.execute_command(u'cd %s\n' % active_dir)

    code_task.on_trait_change(change_directory, 'active_editor')
```

**Note**: You'll have to run this macro, each time you have closed and reopened the editor window.

See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15478940/1225068) and [2](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/macro_overview.html#macro-intro) for instructions on how to create a macro and for more information about macros in Canopy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cd` inside of iPython. `cd` stands for *change directory*

```
> cd /home/username/my_otherdirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on python tab in Canopy and from menu select 'Keep Directory Synced to Editor'. It will set directory containing your source file as your current working directory.You can set any directory as your working directory by selecting 'Change Working Directory' from right click menu