# How to set the directory of IPython shell in Emacs the same as the python file?

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

I am trying to run IPython in Emacs, using emacs 24.3.1, Python 2.7.4, IPython 0.13.2 on Ubuntu 13.04

When I start an IPython shell within Emacs, it defaults to $HOME directory. I try to change to my current work directory by `'cd', 'import os, os.chdir()'`, but after running a snippet of code, work directory always goes back to $HOME.

Is there a way to change work directory, or start Ipython shell the same as the directory of the edited python file? Thanks.

I found a similar question [Setting the working directory of IPython Shell to that of the python file being executed in Canopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972273/setting-the-working-directory-of-ipython-shell-to-that-of-the-python-file-being) but not sure how to implement in Emacs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With python-mode.el, which should be available at Ubuntu:

Run IPython via M-x IPython

Customizations applicable in this case:

```
py-execute-directory
```

When set, stores the file's default directory-name py-execute-... functions act upon.

resp.

```
py-use-current-dir-when-execute-p
```

When `t', current directory is used by Python-shell for output of`py-execute-buffer' and related commands.

Comment: thanks, I added (setq py-use-current-dir-when-execute-p t) to my .emacs file, then start ipython, when use 'cd', it prints my current directory; when us 'os.getcwd()', it still prints HOME directory... so the method only works partially. Since I'm fairly new to Emacs, I guess I need more tweaking of the python environment, thanks anyway!

Comment: @calbear cd /SOME/OTHER/DIR works for me. At start, if py-execute-directory isn't customized otherwise, $HOME is the default.