# Not seeing the entire output after the script runs

Tags: configuration, console-application, ipython

I'm not sure how to word this but I'm not getting the complete history after I run a script. I have some print statements and I see the results print out as it's running. But then when I go back and scroll vertically to take a closer look at the output, the results are gone. In other words the first lines are not displayed.

I have the following statement in my code so it should display all the lines

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 180000)

What do I need to do to see all the output; not just the last part ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase the ipython qtconsole scrollback buffer limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720766/how-to-increase-the-ipython-qtconsole-scrollback-buffer-limit)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to increase the size of the scrollback buffer. If you're using the QT console, there's a StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720766/how-to-increase-the-ipython-qtconsole-scrollback-buffer-limit) that shows how to do that. If you're using ipython from another console, you'll have to look up how to change the size of the scrollback buffer there.

Comment: Using Anoconda with IPython console. How do I increase the size ?

Comment: I don't know Anaconda, but if it uses the QT console that ships with ipython the linked answer should Just Work™.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell what console... newbie. But I tried the statement that was suggested and I see 'undefined name c' or if i drop the c, i see undefined name IPython Widget

Comment: That's because that bit was supposed to go into your configuration file, as it says in the answer. If you run "ipython qtconsole --IPythonWidget.buffer_size=1000" from the shell, does it do what you want?

Comment: Sorry for the silly questions. Do I put this before or after main in my script ?

if __name__ == '__main__':  
       
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 180000)
    ipython qtconsole --IPythonWidget.buffer_size=1000

Either way I seem to be getting an invalid syntax error

Comment: As I said, you'd paste that ipython command into the *shell*, a.k.a. the *command line* or the *terminal*. You shouldn't have to change your script.

Comment: How do I past that command into the shell ? I have an icon in windows that says Anaconda. I open that, oen another icon that is the development environment and then I see my script. I have a menu bar in the development environment with choices such as File, Edit, Source, Run, Debug, Consoles, Tools, View, Help.

Comment: Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 2.0.0 (32-bit)| (default, May 27 2014 15:05:55)
IPython 2.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.

In [1]: ipython qtconsole --IPythonWidget.buffer_size=1000
  File "<ipython-input-1-89ee977389b7>", line 1
    ipython qtconsole --IPythonWidget.buffer_size=1000                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I don't use Microsoft Windows myself, so I can't help you there, but no doubt you'll be able to find someone who can tell you where the command prompt is.

Comment: The command prompt for windows ? the command prompt for IPyton ? The command prompt iptyhon console ? The command promt for what ?